# MongoExpiredSessionError: Cannot use a session that has ended

Tags: node.js, mongodb

I got the error when I trying to connect node to the database. I used the `async` function and try to apply the methods in other similar questions but still got it wrong. Here is my code:

```js
const { MongoClient } = require('mongodb')
const url = "mongodb://localhost:27017"
const client = new MongoClient(url);

async function main(){
    const dbName = 'my-react-admin'
    try {
        await client.connect();
        console.log('Connect to database!')
        const db = client.db(dbName);
        db.collection('users').find({}).toArray((err, data) => {
            if (err) throw err
            console.log(data)
        })
    } catch (e) {
        console.error(e);
    } finally {
        await client.close();
    }
}
main().catch(console.error);
```

Thank you!

Comment: I dont know mongoclient code, but I guess you need to add two more `await`. One of them here `const db = await client.db(dbName); ` And the other one here: `await db.collection('users').find....`

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer, you just have to put `client.close();` to
`((err, data) => { if (err) throw err console.log(data) })`
just like `((err, data) => {client.close();})`.
it'll work.

Comment: What if I don't have .close() method in my code at all?